# JAVA renjin function not found

Tags: java, r, renjin

```
org.renjin.eval.EvalException: lubridate could not be found     at 
org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.load(NamespaceRegistry.java:83)   at 

org.renjin.primitives.packaging.NamespaceRegistry.getNamespace(NamespaceRegistry.java:63) 
...
```

I think the function lubridate is not implemented in renjin?
How can i know what functions are implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lubridate is actually an R package, not a function from R itself. You would need to include the jar for the lubridate package on your classpath.

Unfortunately, it appears that Renjin is not yet able to run this package: see http://packages.renjin.org/packages/lubridate.html for latest status of this and other packages.

Check back in a week or so for the next release candidate, we're fixing a lot of these problems.